# Delete duplicate records from a table oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have duplicate records in a table like below.

```
row no   name  eff_dt            address  pin
1             A       12-10-2007      AN         222
2             B       13-10-2007      AS         223
3             A        15-10-2007      AN        222
4             C        20-10-2007      AZ         222
5             C        27-10-2007      AZ         222
6             C        01-12-2007      AZ         222
```

I used the below query to delete duplicates:

```
delete from customer where rowid in(select rowid from(select rowid,name,eff_dt, address,pin, rownumber() over partition by name, address,pin order by eff_dt)rn from customer) where rn>1
```

The query deleted rownum 3,5 and 6 from the above table.

But according to my need, rownum 3 shouldn't have got deleted since it is different when I compare this with rownum 2. But it got deleted by the query since it is duplicate with respect to rownum 1.

Is there anyway to do duplicate records cleanup in this way? Like compare only adjacent rows? Name and eff_dt are the primary keys of my table.

Comment: What defines a "duplicate" here?

Comment: Hi Tim..Thanks for your reply..I am comparing name,address and pin for checking duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query to delete the duplicate according to your requirement:

```
DELETE FROM CUSTOMER C
WHERE
    ROW_NO IN (
        SELECT
            ROW_NO
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    ROW_NO,
                    --
                    NAME,
                    LAG(NAME, 1) OVER(
                        ORDER BY
                            ROW_NO
                    ) LAG_NAME,
                    --
                    ADDRESS,
                    LAG(ADDRESS, 1) OVER(
                        ORDER BY
                            ROW_NO
                    ) LAG_ADDRESS,
                    --
                    PIN,
                    LAG(PIN, 1) OVER(
                        ORDER BY
                            ROW_NO
                    ) LAG_PIN
                    --
                FROM
                    CUSTOMER
            )
        WHERE
            NAME = LAG_NAME
            AND ADDRESS = LAG_ADDRESS
            AND PIN = LAG_PIN
    )
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d2313dd42f1cb3ebc0d637eb87057de4)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to retain the record with the earliest `eff_dt`, we could try doing a delete with an `EXISTS` clause:

```
DELETE
FROM customer c1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM customer c2
              WHERE c1.name = c2.name AND
                    c1.address = c2.address AND
                    c1.pin = c2.pin AND
                    c2.eff_dt < c1.eff_dt);
```

Comment: This would delete row 3 even though the OP said that they only want to compare to the immediately prior row and that row 3 should not be deleted.

Comment: @MT0 The second comment under the question supports the logic in my answer.

Comment: The OP specifically states "But according to my need, rownum 3 shouldn't have got deleted since it is different when I compare this with rownum 2. But it got deleted by the query since it is duplicate with respect to rownum 1. Is there anyway to do duplicate records cleanup in this way? **Like compare only adjacent rows?**"

Answer (score 0):

```
delete  from customer where rowid in(
select rowid from (
select rowid,name,eff_dt, address,pin, NAME||'--'||ADDRESS|| '--'||PIN as curnt,
LAG(NAME||'--'||ADDRESS|| '--'||PIN , 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY rowid asc) AS prev
from customer)
where curnt=prev);
```

Info: 
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions

Comment: What happens when you have a row where `name = 'A', address = 'AAN', pin = 222` and an adjacent row where `name = 'AA', address = 'AN', pin = 222`?

Comment: Got it. Edited, it will be valid with this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below delete statement, maybe that is what you need.

**LAG(rowno, 1, NULL) OVER (partition by name, address, pin order by eff_dt) prev**

```
DELETE FROM customer a
 WHERE EXISTS 
         (SELECT 1
            FROM (SELECT ROWNO, NAME, EFF_DT, PIN, address,
                         row_number() over (partition by name, address, pin order by eff_dt) rownm,
                         LAG(rowno, 1, NULL) OVER (partition by name, address, pin order by eff_dt) prev
                    FROM customer) b
           WHERE rownm > 1
             AND rowno - prev = 1
             AND b.rowno = a.rowno)
```